# Error: package android.content does not exist

Tags: android, build, expo

I am trying to run `eas build` for my expo React Native project, and the process keeps failing in the `run Gradlew` section, and this is the first error to appear in those logs...

```
Error: package android.content does not exist
```

I am very new to publishing applications, and this is my first app publication using Expo. Does anyone know the solution to this error?

Comment: Hello @TheMilkMan,
were you able to fix this ?
if so how did you solve it please, i'm facing the same issue.

Thanks

Comment: @Iansanalsm You're probably not gonna like the answer, but I had to just start things over. I made a new expo project, copied all of the files from the broken repo into that, and things worked as expecting. The annoying part is just reinstalling all the packages you need. However, to answer your question, no, I was unable to find a solution to fix that repo